# Get ID database From ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have 1 problem and need help.

I have a Activity SearchNote, and i display data from table on it.

Here is my Activity SearchNote

```
private void addDataListViewSearchByNote(){
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String idUser = extras.getString("IdUser");
        Cursor cursor = db.getDataTableNoteWithDateAndType(Integer.parseInt(idUser), et.getText().toString(), SelectTypeNote.getSelectedItem().toString());

        if(!(cursor.moveToFirst()) || cursor.getCount() ==0){
            Toast.makeText(SearchNote.this, "Không tìm thấy dữ liệu", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        String form[] = new String []{db.KEY_CONTENT_NOTE, db.KEY_TYPE_NOTE, db.KEY_DATE_CREATE_NOTE, db.KEY_MONEY};
        int to[] = new int[] {R.id.textView_ContentNote, R.id.textView_TypeNote, R.id.textView_DateCreateNote, R.id.textView_MoneyNote};

        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_note, cursor, form, to, 0);
        ListView listViewManagePage = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_SearchByNote);
        listViewManagePage.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
```

And here is method in DatabaseHelper

```
public Cursor getDataTableNoteWithDateAndType(int id, String date, String Type_Select){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = null;
    int temp = 0;
    if(date.equals("") == true){
        if (Type_Select.equals("Tất cả") == true){
            temp = 1;
        }else{
            temp = 2;
        }
    } else {
        if (Type_Select.equals("Tất cả") == true){
            temp = 3;
        }else{
            temp = 4;
        }
    }
    if(temp ==1){
            res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NOTE + " WHERE " + KEY_ID_USER + " = " + id, null);
    }else if (temp ==2){
            res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NOTE + " WHERE " + KEY_ID_USER + " = " + id + " AND " + KEY_TYPE_NOTE + " = " + "'" + Type_Select + "'", null);
    }else if (temp == 3 ){
            res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NOTE + " WHERE " + KEY_ID_USER + " = " + id + " AND " + KEY_DATE_CREATE_NOTE + " = " + "'" + date + "'", null);
    }else if (temp == 4){
            res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NOTE + " WHERE " + KEY_ID_USER + " = " + id + " AND " + KEY_TYPE_NOTE + " = " + "'" + Type_Select + "'"
                    + " AND " + KEY_DATE_CREATE_NOTE + " = " + "'" + date + "'", null);
    }
    return res;
}
```

I have Spinner and Data which display on ListView is belong to Spinner.
And I'm trying to get ID of item when i clicked on it.

My table TABLE_NOTE has a column's name "Type_Note". I used it to display data on Listview when i select Type in Spinner.

When i select "Tất cả", All data will be displayed in ListView, so i can get excatly ID of item. 
But when i select "Thu" or "Chi", item's ID is not true.

So how can i get _id of item on TABLE_NOTE when i display a part of database on ListView.

Sorry about my English, it's not good

Here is method ContextMenu

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    final String idUser = extras.getString("IdUser");
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info= (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    int index = info.position;


    if(item.getTitle()=="Chỉnh sửa ghi chép"){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Chỉnh sửa ghi chép",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if(item.getTitle()=="Xóa ghi chép"){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(index) ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else if(item.getTitle()=="Đóng"){
        doOpenSearchByNote(idUser);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: where do you want to get `_id` column?

Comment: I edited my Question. I want get _id column when i clicked on item ContextMenu

Comment: @pskink can you help me?